# bash: how to make read with timeout work

Tags: bash

Why doesn't the following script work in bash:

```
while [[ true ]]; do
    read -t2 -n1 check
    if [[ $check == "q" ]];then
        echo "pressed"
        read -n1
        check=""
    else
        echo "not pressed"
    fi
echo "Doing Something"
done
```

I'm using latest macOS and Terminal.app

Comment: What does it do, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: check your bash man page: does the read command take the `-t` option in your version of bash? I believe osx ships with a very old version of bash.

Comment: @glennjackman The `-t` was added to `read` in 2.04. Even macOS isn't *that* out of date :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this (bash version 4.3):

```
while [[ true ]]; do
    read -t2 -N1 check
    if [[ $check ]];then
        echo "pressed"
        if [[ "$check" == "q" ]]; then
            break
        fi
    else
        echo "not pressed"
    fi
echo "Doing Something"
done
```

Please take a look at what

```
$ echo "$BASH_VERSION"
```

prints.